# Consider the set $S=\{-1,0, 1\}$, what is $A=\{xy: x, y\in S\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the set $S=\{-1,0, 1\}$

Set 
$A=\{xy: x, y\in S\}.$
Find all elements of $A$.

Is it $A=\{-1,0\}$ or $A=\{-1,0, 1\}?$ Can you multiply $1$ by itself? Because it's $x$ and $y$....

Comment: yes. Else there would be written $x\neq y$ inside the definition of $A$.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ can be equal so your second option, $A=S$, is correct.

Comment: It is true that both $1$ and $1$ are elements of $A$ (or, in mathematical notation, $1, 1\in A$), so yes, multiplying $1$ with itself is a valid choice.

Answer (score 1):

Taking one of x or y as 0, you have xy=0.  Taking none of x or y as 0, you have xy=-1, if only one of them is -1. taking x=y=1 or x=y=-1 you have xy=+1.  So  $A=\{-1,0, 1\}.$

---

> If $A$ were $\{xy: x, y\in S\ \text{and}\ x\neq y\}$, then we couldnt take x=y=1 or x=y=-1. then A would be $A=\{-1,0 \}.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can multiply $1$ by itself. As long as it is not given specifically, you don't need to assume $x\ne y$.